# how to post interactive flash using FB Android SDK 3?

Tags: android, facebook, post, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to post basic interactive flash content from website which can be directly viewed in wall post itself, i am trying to do something described [here](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hackbook-for-android)(view paranoma images),which in boarder sense is to view flash content in post itself. But the [link](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hackbook-for-android) shows example using a previous SDK, here is code that i wrote that does not seem to be NOT working as its is supposed to

```
Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
            postParams.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
            postParams.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
            postParams.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");               
            postParams.putString("type", "video");
            postParams.putString("video:width", "560");
            postParams.putString("video:height", "400");
            postParams.putString("video:type", "application/x-shockwave-flash");
//            postParams.putString("link", "http://patrickcheatham.com/wp-content/interactives/panoramas/_common/krpano.swf?" +
//                  "pano=http://patrickcheatham.com/wp-content/interactives/panoramas/201012_shanghai_bund/tour_facebook.xml");
            postParams.putString("picture", "http://patrickcheatham.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/shanghai_thumbnail.jpg");
```

**NOTE:**

1. The content to be posted is not yet sturctured completely, so
   working with dummy data.
2. The FB app post perfectly on the wall, just
   not the way it is supposed to be.

If i am missing something please do tell OR if you require additional information,ask for it

Comment: Your links are not linking to anything for me. Also, what path are you posting to with these parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through [Graph API- Post](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/), i came to know about `source` and that did it and also `type` should be `application/x-shockwave-flash` .

```
Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
postParams.putString("message", "the message is from DemoApp");
postParams.putString("name", "Panorama images");
postParams.putString("caption", "Test for viewing panorama images in Facebook");
postParams.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android");
postParams.putString("type","application/x-shockwave-flash");              
postParams.putString("source", "http://patrickcheatham.com/wp-content/interactives/panoramas/_common/krpano.swf?" 
                            +"pano=http://patrickcheatham.com/wp-content/interactives/panoramas/201012_shanghai_bund/tour_facebook.xml");
postParams.putString("picture", "http://patrickcheatham.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/shanghai_thumbnail.jpg");
```